# Decimal increase with arrows - Textfield Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the `OutlinedInput` of Material UI in order to allow the user to input a number.

When the `type` is number, the browser automatically adds two small arrows to the input field.
This is fine.
**HOVEWER** the arrows increases or decreases the input by "1".
I would like them to increase or decrease the input by "0.01".

```
  <OutlinedInput
    type="number"
    placeholder="0"
    value={value}
    onChange={onChange}
    classes={{
      root: classNames(classes.myStyle)
    }}
  />
```

**MyStyle**

```
myStyle: {
  color: "blue"
  width: "90px,
  step: '0.01'
},
```

Comment: include the logic in the `value` variable. ` value + 0.1` something like this. or you could show the full component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add  **inputProps={{ step: ".01" }}**

```
<OutlinedInput
 inputProps={{ step: ".01" }}
    type="number"
    placeholder="0"
    value={value}
    onChange={onChange}
    classes={{
      root: classNames(classes.myStyle)
    }}
  />
```

Comment: can I ask you, what if i want the default number 1.00 and want a step of 1.00 so on clicking the arrows i go to 2.00 or 0.00? thank you

Comment: you can set value as default value